# Spring OAuth2: How do I allow password grant type using java configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-oauth2

In my java server application, I get the following error when trying to authenticate using the password grant flow:

```
TokenEndpoint - Handling error: InvalidClientException, Unauthorized grant type: password
```

I did allow the grant explicitly for the user in question:

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("officialclient")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code, refresh_token, password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                .secret("officialclientsecret")
                .redirectUris("https://www.someurl.com/")
}
```

I am using the following code to retrieve the access token:

```
ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
resourceDetails.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("http://localhost:8080/organizer/oauth/token");
resourceDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList("read", "write"));
resourceDetails.setId("resource");
resourceDetails.setClientId("officialclient");
resourceDetails.setClientSecret("officialclientsecret");
resourceDetails.setUsername("Paul");
resourceDetails.setPassword("password");

OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, context);
return template.getAccessToken().getValue();
```

Is there a global setting for allowing the password grant type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use *Variable Arguments*, not comma separated string value, as you did:

```
.authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code, refresh_token, password")
```

Replace it with:

```
.authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an `AuthenticationManager` to the `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer`. More info [here](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) under Grant Types. Example:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

If you want to use the default manager provided by spring boot for development purposes, you can grab the bean like this:

```
@Component
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class MyAuthorizationServerConfigurer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

public MyAuthorizationServerConfigurer(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

}